# Conditionally add file content using Ant

Tags: xml, ant

I need to add/replace file content if it is not available using Ant. If the specified file content already exists then Ant should not add/replace the content again.

### Original application.xml

```
<application>
    <display-name>customear</display-name>    
    <module>
       <ejb>custom.ear</ejb>
    </module>
 </application>
```

---

### Modified application.xml

```
<application>
   <display-name>customear</display-name>    
   <module>
      <ejb>custom.ear</ejb>
   </module>

<!-- this below content i need to find if exixts or not, if not add the content or do nothing. -->    

    <module>
       <ejb>abcd.ear</ejb>
    </module>

 </application>
```

---

I don't have a choice to use third-party Ant XMLTask or Ant-Contrib tasks because those require additional JAR files to support.

So far I have tried the target below. Running the Ant script multiple times causes the target to add the file content multiple times.

```
  <target name="update-custom-ear" >
      <replace file="${basedir}/application.xml">
          <replacetoken><![CDATA[</application>]]></replacetoken>
          <replacevalue>
            <![CDATA[ <module>
                <web>
                    <web-uri>abcd.war</web-uri>
                    <context-root>/*</context-root>
                </web>
            </module> ]]>
        </replacevalue>         
    </replace>
  </target>
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, a `depends` attribute has been added to the `update-custom-ear` target. The `depends` attribute changes `update-custom-ear` to depend on a new target named `does-abcd.ear-exist-in-application.xml`.

The new `does-abcd.ear-exist-in-application.xml` target sets a property named `abcd.ear-exists-in-application.xml` if `application.xml` already contains the string `abcd.ear`.

The `update-custom-ear` target then uses `unless` to determine if it should run.

```
<target name="does-abcd.ear-exist-in-application.xml">
    <condition property="abcd.ear-exists-in-application.xml">
        <resourcecontains resource="application.xml" substring="abcd.ear"/>
    </condition>
</target>
<target
    name="update-custom-ear"
    depends="does-abcd.ear-exist-in-application.xml"
    unless="abcd.ear-exists-in-application.xml"
>
    <echo>abcd.ear is missing in application.xml. Call replace here.</echo>
</target>
```

### Output if application.xml lacks abcd.ear

```
does-abcd.ear-exist-in-application.xml:

update-custom-ear:
    [echo] abcd.ear is missing in application.xml. Call replace here.
```